# Can I edit a greasemonkey script using js ,instead of the editor?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, greasemonkey

For example, I want to create a GM script, and the function I want to achieve is: after clicking the button I add on a web page such as `"http://example.com"`, my script will automatically generate a statement `//@exclude http://example.com` and adds this line to its metadata instead of manually adding it.

Comment: Why not use `GM.getValue()` to keep the list of domains you don't want the script to execute in? Then at startup, you check if it's one of those and exit if it is.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider it.

Answer (score 0):

GM scripts run in `page/content` context (GM|TM|VM), or `userScripts` context (FireMonkey).

They have no access to the extensions which runs in the `browser` context, nor should they have as it would be a major security risk.

Userscript manager extension developers can implement such features. Currently ...

- **Greasemonkey** *New user script* creates a standard template
- **FireMonkey** *New user script* creates a standard template
- **Tampermonkey** *Create New Script* creates a template with the `@match` for the current active tab
- **Violentmonkey** *Create New Script* creates a template with the `@match` for the current active tab